# "they say" (idiomatic) vs "they say"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, translation

I have a sentence in german that I want to translate:

> Firmen scheinen XY zu benutzen, weil gesagt wird, dass XY besser ist.

I would translate this in this way:

> Companies seem to use XY, because they say that XY is better.

Is it crystal clear that "they say" is used idiomatic here? I don't want to refer to "Companies" here, but to people in general - like, just to something I've heard, nothing I have a source for. Is there a better way to translate this?

Comment: I don't understand the original German, but if hat you want to convey is that what *people in general* say appears to be the reason why companies use X, I think it's unlikely that would normally be understood. By default, most people would assume "they" specifically refers to the aforementioned companies. You could at least *reduce* this ambiguity / misleading phrasing with something like *because XY **is thought to be better***. But to be sure you're understood, just state it explicitly: *because **in their opinion** XY is better* or *because **people think** XY is better*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is it not crystal clear, but most listeners/readers would probably think the opposite: it is crystal clear that **they** refers to **companies**.

You could remove the problem by phrasing the idea passively, as in the German text:

> Companies seem to use XY, because it is said that XY is better.

But that sounds a little stuffy or managerial.

To my ears, this similar construction sounds *a little* better:

> Companies seem to use XY because it is commonly believed that XY is better.

I cannot think of a way to communicate the idea with the casual sound of **they say**.

Comment: Perhaps "because everyone knows"? But only if you can be clear that it's tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Or you could put "they say" first: "They say XY is better, which is why companies use it."